# Naming Worksheet With EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

My worksheet is initially named in the 5th line of my code, but I want to rename it based off the workbook name in my case statement.  It is not getting renamed.  How to fix??

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Today;
string s = d.ToString("MMddyyyy");
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
  ExcelWorksheet objWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");
  objWorksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
  switch (pageName)
  {
    case "abcd":
        worksheetName = "abcd";
        workbookName = "abcd_" + s + ".xlsx";
        objWorksheet.Cells["A1:K20"].AutoFitColumns();
        break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are modifying some unrelated local variable.  You would need to modify the Name property on the sheet object:

`objWorksheet.Name = "abcd";`